# Erro na inicializacão do Apache

Tags: apache

Como solucionar este problema?

```
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:14:33 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Poderia informar mais detalhes sobre o que causou este shutdown inesperado, Claudio? Por exemplo que módulos você tem instalado, qual ambiente operacional, a situação específica que originou esse evento?

Comment: Bom, primeiro pedio o "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0" e baixei o "vc_redist.x64" e dai ao iniciar o Apache mostra me este shutdown.

Comment: Você checou o que o log solicita? Conflito de porta, logs do apache, event viewer para saber se não diz nada complementar para te ajudar a entender onde está o problema?